# RHEL 5 Kernel Panic

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, kernel-panic

I performed some `fdisk` operation on vmdisk. After rebooting I got the following error:

```
unmounting old /dev
unmounting old /proc
unmounting old /sys
switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempt to kill init!
```

Comment: Please use a live cd.  Post the contents of your grub configuration, and the contents of the boot directory for your VM.

Comment: Please define _I performed some `fdisk` operation on vmdisk_. What did you do?